# Not able to run service indefinitley in background

Tags: android, service, background

I am working on below code to run a service in background,but the problem is i am not getting how to run the service indefinitely even though the app is closed,here on press of back my service is stopping.I have read many tutorials but still confused with this.

```
public class HelloService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "HelloService";
    private boolean isRunning = false;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onCreate");
        isRunning = true;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onStartCommand");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    if (isRunning) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Service running");
                    }
                }
                //Stop service once it finishes its task
                stopSelf();
            }
        }).start();

        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onBind");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        isRunning = false;
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onDestroy");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want something that repeats, use `AlarmManager`. If you just want a `Service` in the background it can get killed and woke up. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to make a call to server which will get list of updated data and will show me has a notification,,i need to run the call always in background...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android there is NO way (at least for a third party app) to have a never ending process running. The system can always kill your service. So you can use a foreground service but the system can kill your service even in this case (even with low probability). In addition, you should consider that the cpu can go to sleep. So you should take a wakelock but in this way you can kill the user battery so it's not a good solution. My suggestion is to always work "on event" for example with a brodacast receiver that starts a intent service, it does some work and then exit. The always running processes are simply a wrong design choices on Android.

Comment: good say..,broadcast receiver will this suffice has per my use case?

Comment: If your processing is periodic, you can use an alarm that "calls" a receiver for example, or it could starts a service directly. You can even use the job scheduler api on Android 5.0+.

Comment: you mean i can use a broadcast receiver and set some timing to call my server to get updated list.This works out even though i exit my app?

Comment: Yes, when you set an alarm and the timer expires, it sends an intent to your receiver, then you can: 1) take a partial wakelock 2) call the server with a timeout 3) get the response 4) release the wakelock. When the intent service ends, it closes its process automatically.

Comment: okie thanks a lot..,at least it is clear that i should be using receiver.I will update again if i am not able to work out.

Comment: ,i wanted to know when we use broadcast receiver,server should also implement this (has a broadcast sender) ? i am suppose to call just a webservice in background which is exposed

Answer (score -1):

One Way is to use while loop but keep a check i.e

```
while(true) {
    if (condition != true) {
        Thread.sleep(time);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: this will make sure of running indefinitely ?